# Output all the elements grouped by in sql

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a table in phpmyadmin which has 2 columns one named marca and the other named categoria. I want to group these by marca. I create this sql query to do this but the problem is that it outputs only one category for marca.

```
$sql0="SELECT marca , categoria FROM marche GROUP BY marca ";
```

I want to group by marca and output  in the row of this marca all the categories belonging to it. How is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) for your needs,

```
$sql0="SELECT marca , GROUP_CONCAT(categoria) as category_group FROM marche GROUP BY marca ";
```

By default you should get a comma-separated list of elements in category_group. You can use the PHP explode function to turn that into an array in your PHP logic.